# Avoiding copies in conversion operator to a subset of base classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, conversion-operator

First off: You will yell "[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)!" and you will be right, but for now I'm trying to see if there is a good solution to this particular Y to judge/minimize its compromises compared to other Y for this (large) X.

---

Consider the following variadic template class that inherits from all its template arguments and provides a conversion operator to a subset of them:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct derived : Ts...
{
    template<class... SubTs>
    operator const derived<SubTs...>()
    {
        return { static_cast<SubTs>(*this)... };
    }
};
```

This allows you to do something like this:

```
struct A { int a; };
struct B { double b; };
struct C { std::unique_ptr<int> c; };

using ABC = derived<A, B, C>;

int foo(const derived<A, B>& in)
{
    return in.a + in.b;
}

int test()
{
    ABC abc{ {1}, {3.0}, {std::make_unique<int>(4)}};
    return foo(x);
}
```

The conversion does create a temporary copy to pass to the functions though. So you cannot do the following, because a `unique_ptr` cannot be copied:

```
int bar(const derived<A, C>& in)
{
    return in.a + *in.c;
}

int test()
{
    ABC abc { {1}, {3.0}, {std::make_unique<int>(4)}};
    return bar(x);
}
```

Live code: https://godbolt.org/z/KBoBDl

Is there a solution where:

1. I can pass a non-copyable `derived` (without giving up ownership of course).
2. I do not have to specify which of `A`/`B`/`C` a given member of `in` is from (no `in.get<A>().a`). "Use composition instead of inheritance" is not a solution either<sup>†</sup>. In other words, the semantics of `in.a` (`in->a` would also be ok) should be preserved.
3. The function arguments to `foo` and `bar` spell out the sub-types available in their bodies in a single variadic template list (doesn't necessarily have to be in a `derived`, although I feel the previous requirement forces this). If I don't mention `B` then the function should not have access to `B`'s members (even if the passed in `derived` contains a `B`).

Changing `foo`/`bar` to be template functions would be a setback but acceptable. Note that `template<class T> int foo(T in)` (and removing the conversion operator) violates the last requirement. Also note that I'm in C++17, hence no concepts.

Ideally I would imagine the function signature to look something like `int bar(derived_view<A, C> in)` but I don't see how to unify that with all the requirements. Partial ideas/solutions welcome, maybe it helps.

<sup><sup>†</sup>`derived` *is* my best shot at composing variadically, `A`/`B`/`C` are all wrapper structs already. That's why there should not be any further indirection to accessing the actual data.</sup>

---

Yes, I know, *"this sounds like normal function parameters with extra steps!"*, but I have lots of `foo` and `bar` that take lots of different subsets of tens of `A`/`B`/`C` etc. structs, each one building more such structs. Plain function parameters are the well-explored status quo and they are not a satisfactory solution.

Comment: There's one obvious but disgusting and costly option. Make `derived<Ts...>` derive from all permutations of `derived<Ts... less one element>`. Make `derived<T>` derive from `T`, virtually.

Comment: @T.C. Hah, that is exactly the kind of evil genius I asked the question here for :D To be honest I wouldn't exclude this straight away. Would you mind writing up an answer, including pointing out whatever dangers/costs you see?

Comment: Exponential compile times, to start with. (Instantiating `derived<Ts...>` requires instantiating `derived<...>` for all subsets of `Ts...`.)

Comment: @T.C. Have to virtually derive from _everything_. Otherwise `derived<A, B, C>` will have two `derived<A>` subobjects. Maybe that's not the end of the world. Still gross.

Comment: @T.C. Oh right, it's not just subsets but permutations. Hmmm. I agree that exponential compile times are not the solution but it _conceptually_ solves the problem so elegantly...

Comment: Are you OK with _functions_ all the way instead of data members? There's a lot more room for maneuvering with a function call.

Comment: @T.C. I haven't thought about that, but I can't think of any issues from the usability side right now. So go ahead!

Comment: Sketching the idea: see Eric Niebler's `tagged` in range-v3 (and the ranges TS proposals). If you can make each of your wrapper struct into a `tagged_tuple`, then you can allow conversion into a `tagged_tuple` of references, so long as the tags is a subset.

Comment: @T.C. The "sort by some key to sidestep the permutation problem" comment on the deleted answer is a good point! I'm pretty sure that you can do this even if you don't control the elements (via `typeid`?) with some effort. That leaves "only" the subset problem. Maybe there similarly is a way to tackle that... I will take a look at the `tagged` stuff, thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to make a `derived_view` like you say - then you could easicly change the individual types so that you don't return copies of non-copyable types - by specialization by eg. using `std::is_copy_constructible` ? - i was trying out this, but i don't have more time right now.

Comment: @darune: issue is to have expected syntax (`in.a` or `in->a`).

Comment: @MaxLanghof No, because you can't do anything useful with `typeid` in constant expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If we limit `derived_view` to "can only be used as function argument", then it should be safe to move any used parameters out of a passed `derived` (or `derived_view`) in its constructor and move them back in the destructor:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct derived_view : Ts...
{
    template<class... SubTs>
    derived_view(derived<SubTs...>& original)
      : Ts(static_cast<Ts&&>(original))...
    {
        _restoreOriginal = [&](){
            ((static_cast<Ts&>(original) = static_cast<Ts&&>(*this)), ...);
        };
    }

    // Also allow construction from another derived_view
    template<class... SubTs>
    derived_view(derived_view<SubTs...>& original)
      : Ts(static_cast<Ts&&>(original))...
    {
        _restoreOriginal = [&](){
            ((static_cast<Ts&>(original) = static_cast<Ts&&>(*this)), ...);
        };
    }

    ~derived_view()
    {
        _restoreOriginal();
    }

private:
    std::function<void()> _restoreOriginal;
};
```

Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/CVkmZc7AXSkTiJZx

This is obviously playing with fire if anybody wants to use `derived_view` and access the `derived` (or `derived_view`) it was constructed from at the same time. Placing this in the hands of other users (which is the plan here) will likely lead to disaster sooner or later...